# How to detect touchstart and click events and apply css accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var myVideo = document.getElementById('myVideo');
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var event = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/) ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

$(document).on(event, '.mejs-fullscreen-button', function () {
if (event == 'click') {
  //here it cant catch click event
}//end of click
else {

}//end of touchstart
});
```

how to correctly map here when click or touchstart event starts?
if(event=='click') does not work in window browsers any other way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `event` to your function as well as using **[event.type](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/)** instead:

```
$(document).on(event, '.mejs-fullscreen-button', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'click') {
        //here it cant catch click event
    }//end of click
    else {

    }//end of touchstart
});
```

Comment: It works great.Initially i missed to put event inside function() as param.so unable to catch the touchstart event now its working great